# How get URI from response object after redirect?

Tags: scala, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am send GET request to page `site.com` using Apache HttpClient 4.3.2 lib, the server can redirect me to `site.com/home` or `site.com/login` or not redirect. How get URI from HttpResponse object?

```
def checkLogin(rawRequest: HttpRequestBase) = {
  val client = HttpAsyncClients.custom().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).useSystemProperties().build()
  client.execute(rawRequest, new FutureCallback[HttpResponse] {
    def completed(result: HttpResponse) = {
      if (result.getURI() == "site.com/login") // this is what I want! (or something like)
        parent ! ErrorMsg
      else
        parant ! OkMsg
    }
  })
}
```

I spent more than 2 hours to find a solution but have not found it.